# calling a thread function both as detached and as joinable from different parts of the code in C

Tags: c, pthreads

i'm writing in C (gcc) and I have a function read_serial_device() that will be called as thread. I'm using the pthread library.

Thing is in main() i call this fn and I know i don't need to wait for it to exit. so I can instantiate it in DETACHABLE state.
however in other parts of the code (from another thread actually), i need to create it joinable.

Can I actually call the function as detachable in one case and as joinable in the other? or should I create it joinable always and everywhere?

thank you

Comment: Dmitri makes a good point.  Also learn how to vote up answers that are useful (but might not solve the problem) and accept answers that solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether the thread is detached or not is a property of the *thread*, not the thread function... so nothing is stopping you from creating threads with different attributes that use the same thread function.  The same goes for stack sizes, signal masks, and anything else you can set outside the thread function itself before/when you create the thread.